# Trace back with File Handling : Error:File Not Found

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to read all the files from a specific folder and then read first line of each file , create a list and then match it with the existing list.

below is the code and output looks like my first instance of loop is going fine and then it is throwing some kind of error:

```
import os
import sys
import bz2
import glob

# f = open('C:\\Users\sauris\Desktop\pyfile\out1.txt', 'w')
# sys.stdout = f

path = 'C://Users/sauris/Desktop/pyfile/folder-test'

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    try:
        print('Checking file-', filename)
        handle = bz2.BZ2File(filename, 'rb')
        # print(name)
        # handle = bz2.BZ2File(name, 'rb'
    except:
        raise
        print('no files found')

lst2 = ['But', 'soft', 'what', 'light', 'through', 'yonder', 'window', 'breaks']
firstline = (handle.readline().decode()).rstrip()

st = (firstline.split(' '))

if st == lst2:
    print('Header Validation: OK')
    print('Column Values are Same And In Order')
elif set(st) == set(lst2):
    print('Header Validation: NOT OK')
    print('Headers Are Same But Not In Order')
else:
    print('Header Validation: NOT OK')
    print('Headers Are Different Also Not In Order')

if len(st)==len(lst2):
    print('Number Of Column :OK')
else:
    print('Number Of Column:NOT OK')

handle.close()
```

OUTPUT:

```
C:\Users\sauris\Desktop\pyfile>folder-read.py

Checking file- sampledatafile.txt.bz2
Header Validation: OK
Column Values are Same And In Order
Number Of Column :OK
Checking file- sampledatafile2.txt.bz2

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\sauris\Desktop\pyfile\folder-read.py", line 13, in <module>
File "C:\Users\sauris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\bz2.py", l
ine 96, in __init__
self._fp = _builtin_open(filename, mode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sampledatafile2.txt.bz2'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
bz2.BZ2File(os.path.join(path,filename),'rb')
```

Instead of `bz2.BZ2File(filename, 'rb')`. I think that your only problem is that you're not adding your path correctly.

Comment: Now i am facing Syntax error on list()
C:\Users\sauris\Desktop\pyfile>folder-read.py
  File "C:\Users\sauris\Desktop\pyfile\folder-read.py", line 12
    lst2 = ['But', 'soft', 'what', 'light', 'through', 'yonder', 'window', 'brea
ks']
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: that's a syntax error. You have to be careful. Also, when you publish your code, you have to indent it correctly because it seems that the reading of files is not being done inside the for loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate , now i can sleep . it worked , not sure why syntx error was throwing in , rewrote the code , it worked like charm:)